# sql get values inside variables conditionally

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to get values in variables based on condition as below,

```
DECLARE @HP INT,@PP INT;

SELECT CASE COLUMN_1 
         WHEN 'VAL1' THEN SELECT @HP = COLUMN_CD
         WHEN 'VAL2' THEN SELECT @PP = COLUMN_CD
    END
         FROM TBL
```

no success. how can i do this?

Note: here `COLUMN_1` is `UNIQUE`

Answer (score 1):

The`CASE..WHEN` structure should return with a scalar value, not with a resultset. `SELECT` statement returns a resultset. (The `SELECT @HP = COLUMN_CD` parts)

You have to assign the values to the variables individually like this:

```
DECLARE @HP INT,@PP INT;

SELECT
    @HP = CASE WHEN COLUMN_1 = 'VAL1' THEN COLUMN_CD ELSE @HP END
  , @PP = CASE WHEN COLUMN_1 = 'VAL2' THEN COLUMN_CD ELSE @PP END
FROM
  TBL
```

OR if you do not want to preserve the original value of the variables, you can replace the `@HP` and `@PP` in the `ELSE` part to `NULL`:

```
DECLARE @HP INT,@PP INT;

SELECT
    @HP = CASE WHEN COLUMN_1 = 'VAL1' THEN COLUMN_CD ELSE NULL END
  , @PP = CASE WHEN COLUMN_1 = 'VAL2' THEN COLUMN_CD ELSE NULL END
FROM
  TBL
```